# Can I set the file._id in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I use MongoDB to store my documents. Every document has a unique `id` which is sent by the client. This `id` consists of 36 characters - which are letters, numbers and `-` character.

I want to set the _id parameter to the client ID.

Comment: What do you mean by "set the parameter to client"?

Comment: You should update your question to clarify that you're using GridStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [custom](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) `_id` for your documents, as long as it's unique. It can be any any BSON type except an array. You just need to set the value of `id` field when you're inserting the document:

```
db.coll.insert({ _id : 123456789, foo : "bar });
```

You can also specify a unique id for your document in GridStore, you just pass it as a second argument to GridStore:

```
var gridStore = new GridStore(db, 123456789, "test_file", "w");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just overwrite the document key '_id' with your client id i.e. when you are saving any document add '_id' field to it.

`db.myCollection.insert({'_id':CLIENT_ID, 'data':SOME_DATA })`

Comment: I use node.js & gridstore. I can do the same there?